# Is it possible to apply CSS to a module (and all its components) in Angular?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, sass, angular5

I'm developing a styleguide in which all components to be exported are in a ComponentsModule. We use bootstrap as a CSS framework and Angular 5.1.0.

At the moment, every component must have a reference to the bootstrap files in `@Component({ styleUrls: [...] })`. Is it possible to apply the styles to the ComponentsModule instead, so that every component declared in the module inherits the styles?

Comment: no, you needn't have a reference to the bootstrap files. If you're using angular-cli you can add in your angula-cli.json the common styles . e.g. "styles": [
        "app/css/bootstrap.css",
        "..//font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "styles.css"
      ], If not, just include the css in your index.html

Comment: I did this in the styleguide-app, but the components are exported as a library. In this npm package, there is neither an index.html, nor is it build by the cli, so this approach doesn't work.